# Babel replaces this with undefined

Tags: javascript, jasmine, babeljs

This code

```
beforeEach(() => {
        this.asd= '123';
        this.sdf= '234';
        this.dfg= '345';
        this.fgh= '456';
});
```

has been transpiled by Babel to:

```
beforeEach(function() {
        undefined.asd= '123';
        undefined.sdf= '234';
        undefined.dfg= '345';
        undefined.fgh= '456';
});
```

Why?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Presumably that code is at the top-level scope of a module, and so it's in strict mode (the default for modules is strict mode), or a file that is being evaluated in strict mode (because it has `"use strict"` or because of Babel's defaults).

The short version: If you're expecting `this` to be determined by `beforeEach` when calling your callback, you'll want to use a `function` function, not an arrow function. Read on for why Babel is transpiling as it is:

The fundamental thing about arrow functions (other than being concise) is that they inherit `this` from their context (like a variable they close over), instead of having it set by the caller. In strict mode, `this` at global scope is `undefined`. So Babel knows, at compile-time, that `this` within the arrow function will be `undefined` and optimizes it.

You've said in comments that this is inside another function, but my guess is that it's inside another arrow function, e.g.:

```
describe(() => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        this.asd= '123';
        // ...
    });
});
```

Since Babel knows that `this` is `undefined` in the `describe` callback, it *also* knows that `this` is `undefined` in the `beforeEach` callback.

If you put your code in a loose mode context, or inside a function call where `this` can't be determined at compile-time, it won't do that. For example, in strict mode your

```
beforeEach(() => {
  this.asd= '123';
  this.sdf= '234';
  this.dfg= '345';
  this.fgh= '456';
});
```

does indeed transpile to

```
'use strict';
beforeEach(function () {
  undefined.asd = '123';
  undefined.sdf = '234';
  undefined.dfg = '345';
  undefined.fgh = '456';
});
```

but this:

```
function foo() {
  beforeEach(() => {
    this.asd= '123';
    this.sdf= '234';
    this.dfg= '345';
    this.fgh= '456';
  });
}
```

transpiles to

```
'use strict';

function foo() {
  var _this = this;

  beforeEach(function () {
    _this.asd = '123';
    _this.sdf = '234';
    _this.dfg = '345';
    _this.fgh = '456';
  });
}
```

...because Babel doesn't know how `foo` will be called, and thus what `this` will be.

Comment: This code is located inside nested `describe` block, therefore it is in the closure, not on the global level. Doesn't it have to be working fine?

Comment: @mms27: Show the code. We can't help you with code we cannot see. If this code is in a callback to a function that's *also* defined with arrow syntax, then it's the same issue as the above, just nested.

Comment: Gotcha! Yeah, this most probably is the case.
I probably should just avoid using arrow function and use regular anonymous function instead.

Comment: @mms27: If you're expecting `this` to be set by `beforeEach`, then yes, the callback can't be an arrow function, because `beforeEach` can't control the `this` used by the arrow function. This is the fundamental property of arrow functions: They inherit `this` from their context (like a variable they close over), instead of having it set by the caller.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue, and changed my fat arrow function into a normal function, and it seemed to work again.

```
() => {}
```

changed to

```
function() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions don't have their own `this` or arguments binding. Instead, those identifiers are resolved in the lexical scope like any other variable. That means that inside an arrow function, `this` and arguments refer to the values of `this` and arguments in the environment the arrow function is defined in (i.e. "outside" the arrow function).
In your scenario, `this` at global scope is undefined. At compile-time, babel will transpile `this` within the arrow function as `undefined`.

If you are not very familiar with this, consider reading

- [MDN - this YDKJS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [this & Object prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes)